# Оптимальный вариант сортировки товаров

Tags: php, mysql, сортировка

Есть товар `item`

У него есть основной раздел `division`

И дополнительные разделы `divisions`, в которых так же отображается товар

В базе mysql у `item` есть поле `sort`, и товары сортируются по этому полю

Так вот проблема сортировки товаров в `divisions` — сортировку нужно привязывать еще и к разделу.

Если создавать дополнительную таблицу `items_sort` с полями `item_id`, `division_id`, `sort` — будет очень затратно со стороны ресурсов каждый раз добавлять через `inner join` эту таблицу.

Как бы Вы решили данный вопрос?

Comment: Если вы хотите свою сортировку в каждом разделе, т.е. товары 1 2 3 в разделе 1 должны сортироваться как 1 2 3, а в разделе 2 как 2 1 3 - то ваше решение с таблицей сортировки единственно верное. Правда она же вдобавок будет очень муторной для заполнения ...

Comment: С другой стороны - надо понять почему именно появляется желание в каждом разделе выводить товары по своему. может в базе найдется некая другая информация которая влияет на решение о выведении товара на первые позиции

Comment: Есть некоторые разделы и подразделы, в которых необходимо выводить товары строго по определенному порядку. К примеру, есть платья и брюки + дополнительный раздел праздничной одежды, в котором есть некоторые платья и брюки. В платьях сортировка одна, в брюках другая, а в праздничной должна быть третья. Единственный недостаток доп таблицы - скорость. В некоторых разделах тысячи товаров и нагрузка значительно повышается. А кеш не сделать, так как наличие обновляется каждые 20-40 минут

Comment: А откуда порядок сортировки появляется - сидит некий человек и для каждого товара задает приоритет сортировки в данной подгруппе ?

Comment: Да. Просто перетаскивает товары. Это не во всех разделах, в некоторых просто по новизне сортируется или по цене

Comment: там где по новизне/цене - хранить для группы порядок сортировки и подставлять явно в order by момент формирования запроса. А там где руками ... ну собственно или отдельная таблица или несколько колонок сортировки у item и выбор одной из них (тем же механизмом, что подстановку в order обеспечивать будет). Правда в item оно понятное дело как то криво ибо группы наверняка диначимески добавляться будут, их много может оказаться и колонок ненапасешся